# Palindrome program debugging

Tags: java

The problem is fixed but I need help with creating a method for one of the pieces of code. Any inputs will be appreciated. I tried using void methods but it didn't work. I have highlighted where i want the code to be a method.

```
import java.util.*;
 public class Finalpal {

public Finalpal() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String word;
    int len, counter = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter your word");
    word = scan.next();

    word = word.toUpperCase();

    len = word.length();

    char array[] = new char[len];
    char reverse[] = new char[len];

    for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        array[i] = word.charAt(i);
    }
    for (int j=len-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        array[counter] = word.charAt(j);
        counter++;

    }

    // This part needs to be a method
    for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
        if (array[k] != reverse[k])
        {
            System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
            break;
        }
        if ((array[k] == reverse[k]) && (k == len -1))
        {
            System.out.println("It is a palindrome");
        }
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not filling in the `reverse` array

try

```
for (int j=len-1; j>=0; j--)
{
    reverse[counter] = word.charAt(j);
    counter++;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Correct Scary

Comment: Can you please help me with making a part of this code into a method.

Comment: come on, try it yourself first, learn from **your** mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You have used array[counter] instead of reverse[counter]. You have never filled reverse array

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing this without creating a reversed string to compare to the original...

If I knew the length of the string, I could make a loop that checked the characters on either end to see if they were the same and move inward:

[a] [b] [c] [b] [a]

```
Loop 0: a = a
Loop 1: b = b
Loop 2: c = c
Result: Palindrome!
```

Functions you need:

```
int len = String.length();
char c = String.charAt(int);
```